# Open KDE Konsole in Windows Subsystem WSL, no font in terminal

Tags: fonts, kde-plasma, windows-subsystem-for-linux, konsole

I installed in my Windows VcXsrv X Server and I configured it. On my WSL I installed konsole from KDE. When I open konsole there is no font in terminal. What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: I ran in the same problem with Xming.

Comment: In general, I'd suggest copy-pasting messages (instead of giving a screenshot), and getting the errors in English.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install konsole
```

Open:
press key

windows

search "konsole"

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqd0n.png)